# Problems on running solution on Local Machine (VS 2017)

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 and since I have created two more projects in the solution, when trying Running the solution in the Local machine gives me this error:

> The program '[11400] -------' has exited with code -1073741819
>   (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'. Activation of the Windows Store app
>   '--------!App' failed with error 'Operation not supported. Unknown
>   error: 0x80040904'.

And shows this two alerts in screen:

[image]

[image]

It's driving me mad, because when opened the solution at the first run, it works OK, but without any changes in the code, in the second running throws the error above. I have to close the solution, exit Visual Studio, the enter again and load the solution.

here is my configuration for JIT in the options.

[image]

I have updated Visual Studio, repaired, but it continues to happen.

Any idea why is happenning and how to fix it?

Comment: Same thing. Debug works fine but release fails with the same error